# Spring + HibernateTemplate + AOP for transaction mamangement not working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, spring-transactions

I am using simple "helloWorld"ish application to learn Spring,Hibernate and transaction management using AOP. But is not working as expected.  I am getting exception in transaction management. Details as follows :-

```
Spring version 4.3.8
Hibernate version 5.2.10
HSQL DB version 2.3.4
```

Spring.xml look as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

<!-- Enable Annotation based Declarative Transaction Management -->
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" mode="aspectj"
    transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<!-- THIS IS COMMENTED. Without commenting same result. I TRIED USING HibernateTransactionManager. still got same result.  -->
    <!--
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean> -->


<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:/ProjectRelated/softwares/hsqldb-2.3.4/hsqldb/data/FirstFile"/>
    <property name="username" value="sa"/>
    <property name="password" value="sys"/>
</bean>

<bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" >
    <array>
        <value>com.kaushik.winnersoft.data</value>
    </array>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
</bean>


<bean id="customerDAO" class="com.kaushik.winnersoft.dao.CustomerDAOImpl">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="customerManager" class="com.kaushik.winnersoft.CustomerManagerImpl">
    <property name="customerDAO" ref="customerDAO"></property>
</bean>
```

DAOImpl class is

```
public class CustomerDAOImpl implements CustomerDAO {

private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

public HibernateTemplate getHibernateTemplate() {
    return hibernateTemplate;
}

public void setHibernateTemplate(HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate) {
    this.hibernateTemplate = hibernateTemplate;
}

@Override
@Transactional
public void create(Customer customer) {
    System.out.println("in  dao creating");
    hibernateTemplate.save(customer);
    System.out.println("in  dao creating done");
}
```

I get output as follows

```
Doing
in  dao creating
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Write operations are not allowed in read-only mode (FlushMode.MANUAL): Turn your Session into FlushMode.COMMIT/AUTO or remove 'readOnly' marker from transaction definition.
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.checkWriteOperationAllowed(HibernateTemplate.java:1165)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate$12.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:643)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate$12.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:640)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:359)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:326)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.save(HibernateTemplate.java:640)
at com.kaushik.winnersoft.dao.CustomerDAOImpl.create(CustomerDAOImpl.java:27)
at com.kaushik.winnersoft.CustomerManagerImpl.createCustomer(CustomerManagerImpl.java:20)
at com.kaushik.winnersoft.SpringTest.main(SpringTest.java:14)
```

**Answer**

Based on the coments given below by M. Denium; I did following changes and it worked.

1) Used HibernateTransactionManager instead of DataSourceTransactionManager

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

2) In  removed mode="aspectj"
so it looks like

```
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

Comment: You are using the wrong transaction manager. Use the one that fits your persistence layer. You are using hibernate so use the `HibernateTransactionManager` not the `DataSourceTransactionManager`. And I suggest NOT to use `HibernateTemplate` that isn't recommended anymore since Hibernate 3.0.1 (or the introduction of Hibernate contextual sessions).

Comment: DataSourceTransactionManager part is actually commented in above XML. Sorry for confusion. I removed it from question now. Still I tried configuring HibernateTransactionManager. Still same error.

Comment: and remove `mode="aspectj"` from the `tx:annotation-driven` unless you are really using load or compile time weaving which I heavily doubt. Nonetheless you still need to use the proper transaction manager.

Comment: Wow that worked.

Comment: @M.Deinum can you please add your two suggestions  in above commnet as answer so that I can accept it and give you credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see to problems with your configuration

1. You are not using the proper `PlatformTransactionManager`
2. Unless you are using load- or compile time weaving I doubt the `mode="aspectj"` is really correct.

First you need to use the `PlatformTransactionManager` that supports your persistence technology, as you are using Hibernate 5, you need to use the `org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager` instead of the `DataSourceTransactionManager`. (the latter is for application that only do plain JDBC transactions).

From the `<tx:annotation-driven />` remove the `mode="aspectj"` as I suspect you are actually not using full blown AspectJ but are relying on plain Spring to do this for you.

**Pro Tip:** Instead of using `HibernateTemplate`, which isn't recommended anymore since Hibernate 3.0.1, just use plain `SessionFactory` with `getCurrentSession` instead. This will allow you to write plain Hibernate daos. As suggested in the [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate-straight).